# Неверный формат даты в SQL

Tags: java, sql

Формирую дату `java.sql.Date` в формате ГГГГ.ММ.ДД при запросе `between  cast('2019-02-07' as datetime) and cast('2020-08-26' as datetime)` он мне пишет "выход за пределы диапазона..." меняю местами 08 и 26 все ОК, значит он принимает дату  как ГГГГ.ДД.ММ, как задать правильный формат времени в Java-коде? Также пробую менять местами 08 и 26 но `java.sql.date` ругается. Подскажите что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

UPD1:
запрос:

```
SELECT et.id AS ID,
 pt.short_name AS [Команда проекта],
 a.actv_code_name AS Дисциплина,
 r3.rsrc_catg_name AS Роль,
 r.rsrc_short_name AS Сотрудник,
 et.target_hr AS [План Т/З], 
et.target_start AS [План. старт],
 et.target_finish AS [План. финиш],
 et.create_date AS [Дата добавления], 
et.update_date AS [Дата изменения],
 et.create_user AS [Кто создал],
 et.update_user AS [Кто изменил] 
FROM exec_team AS et INNER JOIN RSRC AS r ON r.rsrc_id = et.rsrc_id INNER JOIN project_team AS pt ON et.kip_id = pt.id INNER JOIN ACTVCODE AS a ON a.actv_code_id = et.dis_id AND a.actv_code_type_id = 7347 INNER JOIN RCATVAL AS r3 ON et.role_id = r3.rsrc_catg_id AND r3.rsrc_catg_type_id = 17071 
 where  et.target_start between  cast('2019-02-07' as datetime) and cast('2020-26-08' as datetime) order by et.target_start
```

P.S. дата введена вручную для проверки

Дата приходит с формы jsp в формате ГГГГ-ММ-ДД
Как формируется дата:

```
Date d1;
if(req.getParameter("d1").equals("")!=true){
d1=Date.valueOf(req.getParameter("d1"));
}
else{
d1=null;
}
Date d2;
if(req.getParameter("d2").equals("")!=true) {
d2 = Date.valueOf(req.getParameter("d2"));
}
else{
d2=Date.valueOf("3000-01-01");
}
filt = FilterBD.FilterPlStart(d1,d2);
```

Comment: Покажите ваш запрос и то как Вы в коде задаете дату.

Comment: @alexey-r Добавил запрос и дату

Comment: Я не очень понимаю зачем Вам вообще формат. Ваша задача передать значение в `between`. `cast` насколько я понимаю преобразует текст в дату. Но Вы же будете передавать **уже** дату в перепэад стейтмет. Просто замените в запросе `cast`  на дату сразу. Будет что-то типа `between  ? and ?`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот способ convert(datetime, '2020-08-26', 'YYYY-DD-MM').
А вообще рекомендую привести все к нормальному формату на стороне приложения.

Comment: Дело в том что это не моя БД, и полного доступа к ней я не имею, а за идею спасибо!

Comment: так в бд и не надо, на стороне java приложения нужно